# Comparing strings from DB

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0, string-comparison

I have a code like below where I want to check for a particular string.

```
string Response = "is name not valid";

(Response.IndexOf("name is not valid", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > = 0)

(Response.IndexOf("is name not valid", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > = 0)
```

Now, I am checking a lot of strings like that where the string value is from the DB and I hard code the strings here as per DB strings. Which condition of the above will become true?

Also, any other better way to do these ocmparision? I have multiple such comparisons.

Comment: What is `DB string` and how is that relevant? I am not sure why you can't test the above 2 lines of code yourself, that should take maybe 1 minute of your time (copy paste and run in a console app). As far as a better way that depends entirely on what you are trying to compare and how, IndexOf is fine but if you want a performance check you should write a performance test and analyze the results. Maybe this check is not the slowest part of whatever operation you are performing.

Comment: @Igor: That is not relevant, that is not your problem. I asked a question, assume DB is database where a table is there and this message column and I retrieve those hard coded messages

Comment: @Igor: Testing yes good point, I am doing. I am also in need of expert opinion

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOf` returns -1 if your string-to-match (or "is name not valid" in this case) does not match in the input string. It returns 0 or a positive number that indicates the exact index where your matched pattern "starts" in your input string.

```
Response.IndexOf("is name not valid", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

should return true even if your input string itself is `"is name not valid"`

I am not sure in your question - why does it make a difference if your "Response" string comes from a DB or from a Krypton matter.

Comment: Arpit. dont worry about Response, I get that from db as a string (List of responses in foreach)